# Cocartesian Square in Category of Sets

Tags: category-theory

I'm undegrad student learning Category Theory on my own and I'm trying to solve some exercises. (Go easy on me).

Ok, so I have two sets $A$ and $B$ and I have the following diagram:

[image: http://presheaf.com/cache/d2z563h4r315x70u725h6g152h2a4h5p.png]

I need to prove that if we put $A \cup B$ we'll have a *cocartesian square*, which I believe is the same as a pushout. Here's my attempt:

1. If $x \in A \cap B$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. In particular $x \in B$, then $f_2(x) = x$ and $g_2(f_2(x)) = x \in A \cup B$. Same way for $x \in A$, we'll get that the diagram commutes.
2. Now suppose I have $h_1: A \rightarrow C$ and $h_2: B \rightarrow C$ such that the diagram commutes. Then obviously there exists a unique function $F: A \cup B \rightarrow C$ with $F|A = h_1$ and $F|B = h_2$. The proof is analogous for the pullback.

Is that enough or there's something missing?

Comment: You say "obviously". Can you carefully define $F$?